# Links to PDF don't work in File Manager

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I have a strange issue. EE 2.6.1.

I can upload and view PDF files. However the file names in the Manager are not links to the files themselves. The manager works fine with images JPG, PNG but doesn't with PDF.

All insights are appriciated!

[image: Bad Link in File Manager]

Answer (score 1):

I think that linking non-image files didn't start happening until 2.7.0. In the [docs for the 2.7.0 update](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-0) under General Changes: "All files regardless of type are now linked for viewing in the File Manager."